# How to calculate the annual rate in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

**Here's the code:**

```
P = int(input("Enter starting principle please.\n"))
n = int(input("Enter Compound interest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly,half-year, yearly)\n"))
r = float(input("Enter annual interest amount. (decimal)\n"))
t = int(input("Enter the amount of years.\n"))

t = 1
while t-1 <= 5-1 :
  final = P * (((1 + (r/n)) ** (n*t)))
  t += 1
  print ("The final amount after", round(t-1), "years is", round(final,2))
```

**When I tried to input:**

1000

1

0.02

2

**it will result like this:**

Enter starting principle please.

Enter Compound interest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly)

Enter annual interest amount. (decimal)

Enter the amount of years.

The final amount after 1 years is 1020.0

The final amount after 2 years is 1040.4

The final amount after 3 years is 1061.21

The final amount after 4 years is 1082.43

The final amount after 5 years is 1104.08

**The problem is, it will not return to the require input number of years (e.g when I tried to input 2 years it will print up to 5 years)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 P = int(input("Enter starting principle please.\n"))
 n = int(input("Enter Compound interest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly)\n"))
 r = float(input("Enter annual interest amount. (decimal)\n"))
 t = int(input("Enter the amount of years.\n"))


 for t in range(1, t+1):
     final = P * (((1 + (r/n)) ** (n*t)))
     t += 1
     print ("The final amount after", round(t-1), "years is", round(final,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting `t` from input, but then immediately ignoring the input and overwriting its value with `t = 1`?

And where is this 5 coming from:  `while t-1 <= 5-1`

Essentially you need a new variable for what you're doing in the loop, separate from `t`.  And "magic numbers" like `5` appearing in code for no reason are something to be avoided.